A little help with confidence interval estimation (for poker database analysis)
I'm a poker player, and I do a lot of database study to understand the frequencies of different profiles of players, to figure out how often they're bluffing and folding in different situations. I'll give you a sample situation that'll hopefully illustrate what I'm trying to work out.
I'm studying bluffcatching, which means situations when I have weak hands that beat their bluffs but I lose to all their strong hands. So in these cases, there is a theoretically optimal bluffing frequency based on the size of their bet. If they are bluffing more than that, I'll always have a profitable call. My objective is to determine where people are bluffing more than they should be with sufficient confidence (say, 90% confidence interval).
So let's say that I'm studying my opponents' bluffing frequencies in a specific line. My data says that on average, people are bluffing ~39% of the time here. I have a total of 4000 trials for this situation, and they bluffed 1560 times. 1560/4000 = 39%. If we assume that the result of each trial is independent of every other trial, and since there are only two mutually exclusive outcomes for every trial (they either have a bluff or they don't), it makes sense to use a binomial distribution to calculate confidence intervals, right?
I used an online calculator for this (https://epitools.ausvet.com.au/ciproportion). I gave the sample size as 4000, number positive as 1560 and chose the Wilson confidence interval method for 90% confidence interval. It gave me the upper and lower bounds as 40.28% and 37.74%. So that's ~ +/- 1.27% error in the 39% bluffing frequency. Is this the right way to interpret the data?
And furthermore, we can do textural analysis within a specific line. The different community cards (common cards that both/all players in the hand are allowed to use) are together called the board, and groups of these cards can be categorized into different "textures". Obviously when you filter for a specific texture within a line, the sample is going to decrease significantly. So the importance of good statistical uncertainty models is magnified. So let's say that in the same line I mentioned above, we're looking at a specific texture.
Let's say that on a particular texture, we have 371 trials and 82 of them were bluffs. So 82/371 = 22.1%. When I input these numbers into the same calculator from above, I get the upper and lower bounds for 90% confidence interval to be 25.84% and 18.77%. So that's ~ +/- 3.53% error. Which means that I can be 90% sure that the lowest the bluffing frequency will be is 18.77%.
So if based on the bet size that I'm facing I need people to be bluffing only 17% of the time, I have a very easy call. But if I need them to be bluffing 21% of the time, then it's much more of a gamble, right?
And one last question is comparing the bluffing frequency of the line average vs the texture average. So for this line, I have 39% +/- 1.27%, but for the texture it's 22.1% +/- 3.5%. How would I go about assessing the confidence interval for the difference between the two? The difference between the two averages is 39% - 22.1% = 16.9%. But what's the uncertainty for this difference? The only thing I found online is that it's the square root of the sum of the squares of the individual uncertainties.
So here it would sqrt (1.27^2 + 3.5^2) = sqrt (1.6129 + 12.25) = sqrt (13.8629) = 3.72%
So for the difference between those two, we would have 16.9% +/- 3.72%? So the most pessimistic assumption would be that this specific texture's bluffing frequency for a 90% confidence interval would be 16.9% - 3.72% = 13.18%?
That's all that I wanted to confirm. Thank you very much for taking the time read to all this and answering my question.

Can you elaborate on your 3rd paragraph? You state your data has an average bluffing frequency of 22.1%, but then you state your sample implies a 39% frequency. How did you get the original 22.1% figure?

@masiewpao Oh, that's an error on my part. It actually is 39% and not 22.1%. I was trying to decide what line's data to use as an example and jumbled them up. I'm going to make that edit now. Good catch!

Off-topic response: your approach is straight out of the commonly accepted notion that you should be attempting to classify your opponent's range (AKA range analysis), for a given situation.  As a retired professional poker player, I will tell you that such an approach should be regarded as a significantly inferior last resort only.  Instead, you should be putting your energy into a deep study of various body languages (verbal and non-verbal), by various poker opponents, in various situations, so that in any given situation, you are over $~90%~$ accurate to make the right decision.

@user2661923 That would be more correct if we were talking about live poker. But all my questions are within the context of online poker. And while you could still construct some kind of a psychological profile for specific opponents, the importance of direct range analysis is far more pronounced when playing online. You have to rely on your opponents' stats to make informed decisions alongside general range analysis.
But even for live poker, having no understanding of range analysis would be a poor foundation (not saying that's what you're recommending).

Good point about online poker, which (because of the prevalence of cheating, in one form or another, for all but the lowest stakes), I suggest that you avoid like the plague.  For example, intelligent subtle (occasional) collusion can never be detected or overcome.  As for live poker, I strongly disagree with your comment.  One only needs a non-mathematical, intuitive (moderately accurate) understanding of range-analysis.  ...see next comment

I regard any deeper understanding/exploration of range-analysis to be a waste of both valuable time and valuable energy that could be much better spent studying body languages.  (Human) poker players only have a finite amount of energy.  Any energy spent studying range analysis is energy taken away from the study of body languages.  Deep range analysis is merely nice filler that allows poker authors to sell their books by deceiving the aspiring professional that the topic is valuable.  The deception is contagious so that the topic is prevalent on poker forums.

@user2661923 I don't know how much online poker you've played in the last few years to have an accurate picture of how much cheating and collusion actually happens. There are good regulated sites that are pretty safe and have very strong anti-cheating measures. I personally know plenty of players playing online in different parts of the world, some of them at high stakes making 200k+ every year. Most make at least 100k a year. Depending on what part of the world you live in, that's quite a lot of money. And quitting online is not an option for me at the moment.

Regarding live poker, much the same can be said about the lack of value of general poker analysis (absent body language, which dwarfs all other considerations).  One glaring exception is tournament play versus non-tournament play.  Among other things, it is very helpful to have a reasonably deep understanding of the technical differences between the two, because (among other things) it provides a starting point (again absent body language) of how opponents think.

In online poker, intelligent collusion can not be detected.  Nor can hacking the online processing to know the opponents hole cards and using such information sparingly (or bribing one of the website's programmers to do the hacking).  For example, if you know that someone has AA, and you fold KK, how will anyone suspect that you folded KK enough to investigate?  Come back when you personally have made $~100k~$ or more for $~3~$ straight years, without engaging in any collusion, hacking/bribing, or any other form of cheating, and then I will give credence to your views.
